# Stripe subscriptions - Offer one month free in the middle of a subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

In my app I am curently implementing a referal program. Everytime someone subscribe using your link you get one month for free.

Until now I was doing it by changing the `pause_collection` of the subscription (which had the effect of not collecting the payment the next month and collect it the month after)

But I realize now that if someone took a subscription for 6 month, it will not change anything for him (or he is lucky and his next 6 month payment will not be collected)

So what I try basically is this:

- **1st of january** I take a 6 month subscription so my next billing date will be the **1st of july**.
- I refer one person the **10th of february**, it changes my billing date to the **1st of august** (so I got +1 month on my current payment), not charging anything until then.
- Charging normal 6 month price the **1st of august** and getting a next billing date on **1st of february**.

So basically being able to increase the time of the current billing period without changing the price or anything.

I don't find on stripe documentation any way to do that do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also playing with this idea. One way could be to give the customer credit, which will be deducted from the next payment. Or you may be able to re-add a trial period that may delay the next payment.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can setup trial period for your customers, and each time extend it by 1 month by calling the Update Subscription API and [specify](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-trial_end) the `trial_end` Unix time.
2. Or you can [generate a Subscription Schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription) from your current Subscription, and modify the Schedule to reflect your change. Be sure to [disable proration](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/update#update_subscription_schedule-phases-proration_behavior). This approach would be complicated and requires testing carefully in Test mode.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to approach this situation. The first one is to discount the amount you charge the customer but keep the same billing cycle while the second option is to change their billing cycle.

For example:
Joe signed up for 1 year on May 1st, 2016 and will renew on May 1st, 2017. Joe invited 3 friends and has earned 3 free months. I would like to wait until August 1st, 2017 to charge him again.

If we continue with above example, giving 3 free months to Joe could mean that instead of charging him $120 for the year on May 1st, 2017 you can charge him $90. The amount is discounted by $10 for each month they get for free. This means they still pay you on the same schedule but pay you less than the full yearly price. If you go down this road, I usually recommend using Invoice Items [1] for this.

You would create an invoice item [2] for a negative amount corresponding to the amount you want to discount off of your customer's subscription for each referral. Those would get added automatically to your customer's upcoming invoice and give him the expected discount when it's time to renew his subscription.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/invoices#adding-invoice-items

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/trials

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription

Answer (score 0):

Goto Subscriptions.
Click on the customer you want to pause.
In the upper right-hand corner, click the PURPLE DROPDOWN BUTTON.
Click "Pause Subscription" and enter the date you want the subscription to resume.